# Write a https client with libevent

Tags: c, https, libevent

I want to write a simple https client with libevent, but it seems that there is no https support in libevent, so is there any solution?

Comment: libevent is about making scalable socket servers, not clients. Go use libcurl if you need an http/https client in C.  http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: Check [example1](http://www.ideawu.com/blog/2013/09/libevent-http-client-example.html) and [example2](https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/sample/https-client.c).

Comment: Thank you Jayesh, it is just what I want

Comment: @Jayesh please update the example1's link to http://www.ideawu.com/blog/post/76.html

Comment: @ideawu No issue. It will appear with your comment as my comment not editable. Thanks